# Count number of comments in a pivot table

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a problem where I need to count the number of comments in the pivot table. The comments are mentioned in text at a row level in the data set. What I need to do is to count the number of comments along an index column and one other value funciton. I am using the following code :

```
pivot_account= pd.pivot_table(data_account, values=['Account_type', 'Comment'], index=['Function'],
                 aggfunc={'Account_type': lambda x: x.count(),
                          'Comment': lambda x: x.count()})
pivot_account
```

**The column comment is a categorical column consisting of all the comments. But I need value count for that. That's it.**

So the Pivot should look something like this

```
Function  Account_Type   Comment
HR .      2              10
IT .      4              20
```

Which means that HR . department has got 20 comments in total. I am not concerned in viewing the comments at this level.

When I run the above code, I get similar output for both the Account_Type and Comment and there is no error.

```
 Function       

                      Account_Type    COMMENT
Business Development     3                3
```

and so on which shows the same number everywhere.

The dataframe looks like this

```
Function  Account_Type   COMMENT
HR          1             XYZ
HR          1             ABC
HR          1             BCD
IT          1             Hello
IT          1             How Are you
```

So the output should be the count of total account_type variable and the count of comments by the function

Comment: Please read about [mcve](/help/mcve) and [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask). In particular will be great to have (at least) a sample of your original df.

Comment: Can you please share an example of what your `data_account` looks like (by editing your question to include it)

Comment: `aggfunc='count'`?

Comment: @rpanai: updated the dataframe with the structure.

Comment: @politicalscientist: Not sure about the best way to count so used a lambda function there. I know its not an aggregate  function but nothing els was working for me.

Comment: It's not reproducible. The original `df` can't possibly return the output you provide. What do you want to do with `Account_Type` column?

Comment: Account_Type is a multi option column. Like it gives options like 1,2,3,4,5 like an open ended survey question. I just want to show the relation between the account_type col: for ex: 5 people have answered this question but did not put any comment.. so the output will have 5 for account_type col and 0 for the comment col.